# firebase onAuthStateChanged giving null on opening a link on new tab

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for authentication in react app. Whenever I open a link in my app on new tab auth.onAuthStateChanged gives a null rather than giving the signed in user. I don't face this issue whenever I reload my page. But this happens whenever I open a nav link on new tab. I had gone through all the similar articles from stack overflow and other resources and changed my code accordingly the problem still remains the same. currently my code looks like this

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
});

export const auth = firebaseApp.auth();



useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(null);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

If you have faced similar issue. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I am dealing with a similar situation today.

I am using the newer Firebase Auth API so the issue might differ from yours.
For me, the issue is caused by calling [setPersistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#setpersistence) on javascript loading.

I basically call [getAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#getauth) then [setPersistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#setpersistence); this lead to reinitialize local storage persistence on document load.

When I open a new tab, the current tab's `onAuthStateChanged` gets triggered by `setPersistence` called in the new tab.
IMO, this should be classified as a bug.

Anyway, the modern (current SDK when I post this answer) workaround is to assign persistence mode from the beginning. That is using `initializeAuth` instead of `getAuth` and supply persistence mode there.

For me, it is:

```js
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: [
    browserLocalPersistence,
    indexedDBLocalPersistence,
  ],
  popupRedirectResolver: browserPopupRedirectResolver,
});
// `setPersistence` was removed
```

Comment: Fantastic sample on `initializeAuth`, never know that. I was doing the exact same thing, calling setPersistence separately after getAuth, which consistently causes user to be null when multiple tabs are opened. I think this has something to do with this explanation provided at the end of the [official documentation][1]:

> multiple tabs opened and then switches to none or session persistence
> in ...
> persisted in session or none and on all other tabs, the user will be
> signed out.

  [1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence